# Malware on Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, malware

I am working on a Wordpress website hosted on Godaddy and struggling with a Malware issue.

Every now and then the webpages start displaying thousands of random links on top of the pages.

When I searched for the texts in the content files, the only place I could find them was in comet cache.

If I delete the cache files, the links go away but again come back after few days.

Can anyone please suggest how can I prevent such a scenario and what all steps I can take to secure my website from such vulnerabilties.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of things that could be causing it. Check all of the following to help remove security holes:

- Are you running the latest version of WordPress? If not, there could be a known vulnerability that is being exploited.
- Are all your plugins up to date? For the same reason as above - a poorly written WordPress plugin can open up security holes.
- Do the WordPress files and folders have the correct CHMOD permissions on the server? If not, you're asking for trouble.

**I'd recommend any/all of the following as further reading:**

- http://www.wpbeginner.com/wordpress-security/
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Comment: Thanks, I will implement all this :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do this work on your own, and you're working with GoDaddy, they offer (and now own) Sucuri which is a security service that will scan and clean your site.  You can do this one-time, or pay for a monthly service that will continuously protect and restore your site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking for an option that is free as its for a self-funded small project :)